# How to publish events to eventhub from different location?

Tags: azure, events, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send events to eventhub. But I am getting error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Same program (Sample program from MSDN) working with Eventhub with location SouthIndia. It is not working for Eventhub with the location Central US.

What is the role of location in eventhub? How can I send the events to the Eventhub in Central US?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unlikely that you Event Hubs is not available or has issues. Have you checked [Azure Service Health](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/features/service-health/)?

Try standing up another "vanilla" Event Hub in the East US and see if you can connect to it.

The only other difference between an Event Hub hosted in South India and one in Central US is that they are serviced out of different data centers. There is likely a firewall between your machine and the East US that is not allowing the connection.

Try using the [Event Hubs Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-runtime-rest) using a simple https call or client (e.g. PostMan) and check the results of the request and response to try get a better idea of where the error is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, my company firewall is stopping me to access to data center in US.

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it.